how to update go version in linux
I'm reading learning go.
And to update the go development tools in Linux, it says(Page 15):
mv /usr/local/go /usr/local/old-go
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.15.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
rm -rf /usr/local/old-go

why do we need to back up the old go?

It's just erring on the safe side. If you're running low in disk space, you can delete the old version without concern because the official Go side keeps almost all historical versions in its archive, and you can always download an old version again, were there any issues.


why do we need to back up the old go?

Like most backups: in case something goes wrong and you want to put it back.

why not delete it first?

It’s pretty safe to skip that step and delete the old version immediately, yes. The official installation documentation even does that:

$ rm -rf /usr/local/go && tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.22.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz


